# Is it possible to add effects to text in a TextView?

Tags: android, text, textview, effect

In my splash screen I have a TextView that it shows the name of application. Is it possible to add effect(s) (for example shade) to this text?

Comment: I afraid, the picture stretches or compresses in different screen sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this to put the shadow, it works

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:shadowColor="#555555"
    android:shadowDx="5.0"
    android:shadowDy="5.0"
    android:shadowRadius="3.0"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of-course you can make your splash screen more innovative with Shimmer Effect.

If you implement then name of application on splash screen will have glow effect from left to right.
You can see my answer for this effect.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327956/2022000