# Text Animation from left to right like shine in Android

Tags: android, animation

I don't know what type of animation it called, but I want to implement it as shown below. I saw that animation in iOS.

[image]

As you can see that, sentence **slide to cancel** will animate from left to right like there is a light behind it.

I don't know what to use. I tried some animation like Alpha, but can't achieve that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try this link: 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/01/create-frame-animation-with.html

Comment: @ViragBrahme, its not what i am searching for.. :(

Comment: Didn't realize that this was for Android, so I set up a CSS animation... I don't do any android, but I'd assume that won't work for you... Here's the demo anyway: http://cdpn.io/BpgyE

Comment: @brbcoding, hm...CSS can be used in our `WebView`. well thank you very much for your effort.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my demo, please try it

https://github.com/FrankNT/TextViewSlideEffect

Regards,
Frank

[image: Text Animation from left to right like shine in Android]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another IOS like slide text effect,

https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android

Comment: great simple and straightforward

Answer (score 4):

Got solution by using **Spannable**

Following is Thread class which continuously run with interval of 100 ms.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    //used for stopping thread
    boolean flag; 

    //init flag to true so that method run continuously
    public MyThread() {
        flag = true;
    }

    //set flag false, if want to stop this thread
    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (flag) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(intervalMiliSeconds);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Spannable spn = new SpannableString(txtView
                                .getText().toString());
                        spn.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),
                                startPosition, endPosition,
                                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        txtView.setText(spn);

                        startPosition++;
                        endPosition++;
                        endPosition %= (lengthOfString + charGaps);
                        startPosition %= lengthOfString;

                        if (startPosition == 0) {
                            endPosition = charGaps;
                            startPosition = 0;
                        }

                        if (endPosition > lengthOfString) {
                            endPosition = lengthOfString;
                        }

                        Log.d("Home", "Start : " + startPosition + " End : " + endPosition);

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use above code, use following implementation.

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

int charGaps = 3;

int startPosition = 0;
int endPosition = charGaps;

int lengthOfString = txtView.getText().length();

MyThread thread = new MyThread();

thread.start();
```

**Output**

[image]

Still better answers will be more appreciated.. :)

Comment: This works great! But how to increase the speed of this effect mate!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about Shimmer Effect. Facebook made library for that.
It will help you to show glow effect from left to right with many more options.

You can see full documentation there.
[Shimmer Library](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways:

1) working with openGL and use Shaders to make this effect.

2) create a layer above text which contains a [transparent][white][transparent] gradient and animate him.

Comment: um...trying..catch you later.